# error: 'class std::unique_ptr<std::set<long unsigned int> >' has no member named 'size'

Tags: c++

I am trying to debug the existing code in our application written with C++,while I am trying to print a unique_pointer to a std:set of type unsigned long, I am facing a compilation error

> `error: 'class std::unique_ptr<std::set<long unsigned int> >' has no
>   member named 'size'`

below is my code snippet which I am trying to print using cout.

```
auto current_list = std::make_unique<std::set<uint64_t>>(); 
std::cout << "Number of elements in current_list is : " << current_list.size();
```

I am new to unique_ptr, I had tried even with Iterator initialized with current_list.begin() but  non of these helpers are associated with the variable current_list.

Please help me understand where I am missing.

Thanks,
Srini.

Comment: Make it `current_list->size()`. After all, `current_list` is not a `set` but a (smart) pointer thereto.

Comment: `current_list` is smart pointer pointing set<uint64_t>. using `current_list.get()`, you can handle set<>. trying `current_list.get()->size()`.

Comment: @Jain you don't need to use `get()->`, just `->` will suffice, as Igor showed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Smart pointers are mostly like pointers, you need `->` to access member of pointee:

```
current_list->size()
```

Alternatively:

```
(*current_list).size()
```

or, for `std::unique_ptr`/`std::shared_ptr`:

```
current_list.get().size()
```

(and don't forget to check for `nullptr` before de-referencing it).